# Counting words in PHP

Tags: php, substr, counting

I have a problem with counting words in PHP, this is my code:

```
$word=substr(stripslashes(strip_tags($row['short_story'], '<a></a>')), 0,100 )."...";
$tpl->set( '{word}',$word);
```

on that code i just can show URL links in my result, i need to show complete style and HTML codes, so i changed to this:

```
$word = substr( stripslashes (strip_tags($row['short_story'], '<a><b><i><u><br></a><div></div>')), 0,400 )."...";
```

i changed this:

```
<a></a>
```

to:

```
<a><b><i><u><br></a><div></div>
```

But problem is, i have to set word limit over 400-500 if i want to show my result correct! because with 100 0r 200 word limit, HTML codes will be broken!

My question is, how i can use word count, but counting only numbers and letters? for example in this code:

```
<div style="color:red;">hello</div>
```

i need to count only **hello** word. is that possible?

Comment: tried the DOM parser?

Comment: I'm not professional with PHP and i don't know what are u talking about :( sorry

Comment: [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) can be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code: it will work only when you know what tags are included in your string.

```
<?php
$tag_word = '<div style="color:red;">hello</div>';

// You can add any number of tags ex: strip_tags($tag_word, '<div><a><img><p>');
$word = strip_tags($tag_word, '<div>');
echo count($word);
?>
```