# PHP, I want to count the number of words in a string with more than six letters

Tags: php

I want to count the number of words in a string with more than six letters.

For example:

`$x = number of words with more than 6 letters("Elephant shoe penguin food telephone");`
`$x=3;`

Do you know how?

Comment: explode at space, filter out all words with less than 6 characters, count what is left.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself? Where's your coding efforts?

Comment: SO is not a code factory. Instead, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you include in your post what you've already tried, you'll get more help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting words in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994044/counting-words-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp:

```
$x = preg_match_all("/\\w{6,}/", "Elephant shoe penguin food telephone", $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the string and check with `strlen` for more then 6 chars.

```
$x = 0;
$string = "Elephant shoe penguin food telephone";
$explString = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($explString as $word){
   if(strlen($word > 6)){
       $x++;
   }
}

echo $x; //Returns 3;
```